# CSS animation overloads CPU

Tags: performance, css, css-animations, will-change

I have an animation and JS for alternating 2 divs and change their background images (from an array of a few dozens images), sort of interchangeable divs. Everything works just fine, however when the animation runs I can see that my CPU is at 100%. At first I thought it might be due to setInterval, however when I changed the code from alternating the images to just increase a number with each iteration and log it to console - I saw dramatic CPU overload decrease, of about 40-50%. So I understood it might be due to animation.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="wallpaper wallpaper-1" id="wallpaper-1"></div>
<div class="wallpaper wallpaper-2" id="wallpaper-2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.wallpaper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    16% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

And JS that makes it all tick:

```
Wallpapers.get().then(function(list) {
    var wp1, wp2, divs = [], path, bgs = [], counterBgs = 0, bgsLength, currentId, doInterval;
    wp1 = document.getElementById('wallpaper-1');
    wp2 = document.getElementById('wallpaper-2');
    divs = [ wp1, wp2 ];
    path = 'assets/img/wallpapers/';
    bgs = list.data;
    bgsLength = bgs.length;

    //Preload images
    for(var i = 0; i < bgsLength-1; i++) {
        var wp = new Image();
        wp.src = path+list.data[i];
    }

    function manageBg() {
        setInterval(function(){
            doInterval();
        }, 4000);
    }

    doInterval = function doInterval() {
        currentId = counterBgs % bgsLength;
        if (counterBgs % 2 === 0) {
            wp1.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + path + bgs[currentId] + ")";
            wp1.classList.add('animate');
            wp1.style.zIndex = 1;
            wp2.style.zIndex = 0;
            setTimeout(function() {
                wp1.classList.remove('animate');
            }, 5950);
        } else {
            wp2.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + path + bgs[currentId] + ")";
            wp2.classList.add('animate');
            wp1.style.zIndex = 0;
            wp2.style.zIndex = 1;
            setTimeout(function() {
                wp2.classList.remove('animate');
            }, 5950);
        }
        counterBgs++;
    };
    doInterval();
    manageBg();
});
```

Any ideas how to reduce the CPU overload?

Comment: which  browsers did you test on? put that info in your Q

Comment: are the images hi res?

Comment: @Tasos a good guess would be chrome, since that's the only browsers he's targetting with his css

Comment: @Tasos As Jaromanda X noticed, I'm targeting webkit-based browsers (eventually this project is supposed to run on Android). Tested in Chrome.

Comment: so give it a test with firefox. at least that way you know its not a browser issue. and you dont need i think (-webkit-) in front of those css rules. chrome works fine without. as i remember when using dev tools if you have both -webkit- or non the -webkit- ones get crossed out anyway. you only need those nowdays when you are hacking the browser with css

Comment: why not use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`?

Comment: how big are the images in megabytes or are they small?

Comment: i just noticed you are using (transform: translateZ(0);)  to put the wallpapers on the hardware layer. have you tried without?

Comment: @Tasos For some reason it didn't work on FF, but did work on MS Edge. I did see a CPU load increase, but not as dramatic as in Chrome, only about 10%. I tried to use it also without vendor prefix, but it didn't have any affect on Chrome, I still saw a CPU load increase of about 50%. The image size vary from 100KB to 400KB.

Comment: @Tasos Yeah, I tried to move the load to GPU by adding `transform: translateZ(0);`. It somewhat helped, the load was reduced by 3-4% in average. Without it the CPU was constantly on 100%.

Comment: @Aziz It doesn't really matter. The tests I made shown `setInterval()` doesn't overload the CPU, but CSS animation does.

Comment: @Igal can you create a jsFiddle demo so we can test it too?

Comment: well chrome dev tools has some options to analyze -- try (profile) and (audit) options to see the reports

Comment: I can run a similar animation on chrome and firefox and edge, without the prefixes, all three use about 3% CPU at most on a 5 year old 4 core AMD with a low to mid spec ATI video card - the only difference with my code is the complete lack of setInterval/setTimeout - I use `animationend` event to trigger the next image and never have to bother with z-index at all

Comment: Unable to duplicate the reported problem. No performance issues were noticed using this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/nitawuxaza/edit?js,output) of your code to display 100 large images and the [Google Chrome Profiler](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling).

Comment: @JaromandaX I can't use `animationend` since I need each animation to begin a little before the previous animation ends, to keep visual consistency.

Comment: actually you can if split your animations - I'll make a fiddle in a bit to show the non settimeout/setinterval way of doing this (I think)

Comment: @Roberto That's interesting... Yesterday it was tested on 2 machines, Windows and Linux, and both showed very high CPU activity. Today I test it on the Windows machine, after restart, and even though the CPU usage is still much higher, it's no way near yesterday's 100%. Even though there are other `setInterval()` involved on the same page, the CPU is in the region of 40-50%, which is still pretty high, but better than yesterday. Will have to keep testing it.

Comment: @JaromandaX Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: as promised - https://jsfiddle.net/wmkvdd4x/

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry for this late response, I was overloaded at work. Thank you for this code, I'll try to implement it a bit later, will let you know about the results. Thanks again!

Comment: Shouldn't the preload be `for(var i = 0; i < bgsLength; i++)`? Now you are only preloading the first one of the array (`i==0`), and you never get to `i==1` because `bgsLength==2`, and `<(2-1)` can never be equal to `1`.

Comment: @Tasos False. Only the last property will overwrite a former, doesn't matter which one is prefixed. E.g. `-moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 2px;` -> W3 standard is used, `border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 3px;` -> Mozilla prefix is used. Also, for experimental features some browsers still rely on their vendor-prefixed implementation. This differs per property.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is [will-change](/questions/tagged/will-change) property of css.

> **will-change** is a property that optimizes animations by letting the browser know which properties and elements are just about to be
>   manipulated, potentially increasing the performance of that particular
>   operation.
>
> Article Source: [will-change - css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/)

The will-change property will use **Hardware Acceleration** in order to reduce load of your **CPU** and allocating your CSS3 animation/transformation to the **GPU**.

> #### The Old: The `translateZ()` or `translate3d()` Hack
>
> For quite some time now, we’ve been using what has been known as the
>   translateZ() (or translate3d()) hack (sometimes also called the null
>   transform hack) to trick the browser into pushing our animations and
>   transforms into hardware acceleration. We’ve been doing that by adding
>   a simple 3D transformation to an element that will not be transforming
>   in three-dimensional space. For example, an element that’s animated in
>   two-dimensional space can be hardware-accelerated by adding this
>   simple rule to it:
>
> ```
> transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
> ```
>
> Hardware-accelerating an operation results in the creation of what is
>   known as a compositor layer that is uploaded to and composited by the
>   GPU. However, force-hacking layer creation may not always be the
>   solution to certain performance bottlenecks on a page. Layer creation
>   techniques can boost page speed, but they come with a cost: they take
>   up memory in system RAM and on the GPU (particularly limited on mobile
>   devices) and having lots of them can have a bad impact (especially on
>   mobile devices), so they must be used wisely and you need to make sure
>   that hardware-accelerating your operation will really help the
>   performance of your page, and that a performance bottleneck is not
>   being caused by another operation on your page.
>
> In order to avoid layer-creation hacks, a new CSS property has been
>   introduced, that allows us to inform the browser ahead of time of what
>   kinds of changes we are likely to make to an element, thus allowing it
>   to optimize how it handles the element ahead of time, performing
>   potentially-expensive work preparing for an operation such as an
>   animation, for example, before the animation actually begins. This
>   property is the new will-change property.
>
> ### The New: The Glorious will-change Property
>
> The will-change property allows you to inform the browser ahead of
>   time of what kinds of changes you are likely to make to an element, so
>   that it can set up the appropriate optimizations before they’re
>   needed, therefore avoiding a non-trivial start-up cost which can have
>   a negative effect on the responsiveness of a page. The elements can be
>   changed and rendered faster, and the page will be able to update
>   snappily, resulting in a smoother experience.
>
> For example, when using CSS 3D Transforms on an element, the element
>   and its contents might be promoted to a layer, as we mentioned
>   earlier, before they are composited in (drawn onto the screen) later.
>   However, setting up the element in a fresh layer is a relatively
>   expensive operation, which can delay the start of a transform
>   animation by a noticeable fraction of a second, causing that
>   noticeable “flicker”.
>
> In order to avoid this delay, you can inform the browser about the
>   changes some time before they actually happen. That way, it will have
>   some time to prepare for these changes, so that when these changes
>   occur, the element’s layer will be ready and the transform animation
>   can be performed and then the element can be rendered and the page
>   updated in quickly.
>
> Using will-change, hinting to the browser about an upcoming
>   transformation can be as simple as adding this rule to the element
>   that you’re expecting to be transformed:
>
> ```
> will-change: transform;
> ```
>
> You can also declare to the browser your intention to change an
>   element’s scroll position (the element’s position in the visible
>   scroll window and how much of it is visible within that window), its
>   contents, or one or more of its CSS property values by specifying the
>   name of the properties you’re expecting to change. If you expect or
>   plan to change multiple values/aspects of an element, you can provide
>   a list of comma-separated values. For example, if you’re expecting the
>   element to be animated and moved (its position changed), you can
>   declare that to the browser like so:
>
> ```
> will-change: transform, opacity;
> ```
>
> Specifying what exactly you want to change allows the browser to make
>   better decisions about the optimizations that it needs to make for
>   these particular changes. This is obviously a better way to achieve a
>   speed boost without resorting to hacks and forcing the browser into
>   layer creations that may or may not be necessary or useful.
>
> **Article Source** - [Everything You Need to Know About the CSS will-change Property](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/)

Your css will be

```
.wallpaper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    will-change: transform, opacity;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    16% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
```

---

### Other Useful Sources:

- [Everything You Need to Know About the CSS will-change Property](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/)
- [CSS-TRICKS Article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/)
- [SNOOK.CA](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/will-change)
- [W3C Editors Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-will-change/)
- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)
- [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=will-change)
- [will-change: update browser support](https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera/pull/330)

Comment: That's quite a big quote. Try to extract what is useful for this specific case. *Why* would will-change help this user.

Comment: The whole thing is useful here so can i remove the quotes? Just will mention source in the bottom!!

Comment: @Igal Please try this and let us know your CPU load